# How to set date to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to first time use firebase. I created extremely open rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete, create: if 1 == 1;
 match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write, update, delete, create: if 2 == 2;
      }
}
  }
}
```

then I wanted to send my test message to the serwer (I successfully instal login/register and reset app, and now, my user are logged).

```
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth, db, logout } from "./firebase";
import { query, collection, getDocs, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

     const SaveDateBase = () => {
          e.preventDefault();
  db.collection('Books').set({
            title: "pokemon"
          })
         }
return (<>
(...)
<button type="submit" onSubmit={SaveDateBase}>Save changes</button>
</>
```

Needles to say, that I created "Books" collection with one example of my work.

Answer (score 2):

##### Problem in your rules

Your rules allow reading and writing a top-level `users` collection, and all data under there. But your code tries to write to a top-level `Books` collection. Since none of your rules mention this collection, that write is rejected.

---

##### Problem in your code

In addition this code won't work:

```
db.collection('Books').set({
  title: "pokemon"
})
```

You're trying to write directly to the `Books` collection, which is not an option (and should be giving you a pretty explicit error). If you want to [add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) to the `Books` collection:

```
db.collection('Books').add({
  title: "pokemon"
})
```

If you want to [set a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), you'll need to specify the document ID too:

```
db.collection('Books').doc('MyFirstPokemonBook').add({
  title: "pokemon"
})
```